# How can I redirect back with query string?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that includes tabs of different data. The tabs are activated by query string. After saving the content of the form that was submitted, I need to redirect back to it to show the corresponding tab using the query data. How can that be done?

currently I am using this for redirection:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation);
```

but this returns to the first tab even there were no changes made on that tab. I saw something like

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->withQuery('tab'=>'info');
```

but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `Redirect::to()` then is simple.

```
return Redirect::to('route_name?q='.$append_data)
```

If you want to use `Redirect::back()` then do these following

```
# Pass the value while redirecting
return Redirect::back()->with('query_data', 'some_data');
```

And add condition to your blade file.

```
@if(!empty(Session::get('query_data')) && Session::get('query_data') == 'some_data')
<script>
$(function() {
    //Change the tab using javascript or
    //use location.href to refresh after appending query params to url.
});
</script>
@endif
```

Comment: For me, `Redirect::to(` needed a "\" in front of it, and even then, it abandoned the query string parameters.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably not the best practice, but I already used it in `L5.8` to redirect back with query string and it works as expected.

```
# Clear previous url from query string
$previousUrl = strtok(url()->previous(), '?');

return redirect()->to(
    $previousUrl . '?' . http_build_query(['foo' => 'bar'])
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#using-the-session) for this:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('tab', 'info');
```

To get info from session, use `session()` global helper which works in controllers and views:

```
session('tab');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

```
return \Redirect::route('route_name',['query1'=>'query1value','query2','query2value']);
```

[More Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects)